# Is it a good idea to aggregate ViewModels?

Tags: wpf, viewmodel

Is it a good or bad idea to have a ViewModel as a property of another ViewModel?

For example:

```
public sealed class ContentManagerViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public FindViewModel Find { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's good, if it helps. But it all depends.

Usually I do have aggregated viewmodels. E.g. I may have a main window viewmodel. It may consist of different parts. Each part may be a separate view model...

If you could describe your particular architecture, we may give better advice :)..

Cheers, Anvaka

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate ViewModels you do only having relations between them. If thats the case you should better use the Mediator pattern with a concrete Messaging System.